# WP Запись в кастомную таблицу результат Promise

Tags: php, wordpress, база-данных

Есть кастомная таблица WordPress в которой необходимо перезаписывать данные получение по fetch запросу.

php запрос на запись в ячейку.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_updateDB', 'updateDataBase' );
function updateDataBase(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';

    $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'json' => $_POST['text'],
        ),
         array('id' => 0),
         array('%s'),
    );

    wp_die();
}
```

Запрос формируется асинхронной функцией:

```
let getSports;
async function getData() {
        let response = await fetch('https://api1.test.com');
        if (!response.ok) {
            const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
            throw new Error(message);
        }
        let result = response.json();
        return await result
    }
    getData().then(result => {
        let data = JSON.stringify(result, null, "\t");

        return getSports = result; 
     }
///// Update Date
    $('#btn_update').click(function(){
console.log(typeof getSports); /// object ~3.5Mb НО НЕ ПИШЕТ В БАЗУ!
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'updateDB',
                text: getSports, /// Тут надо передавать значение в php переменную $text. Но они не пишутся. Просто строку пишет. 
            },

            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                $('#btn_update').text('Обновление базы, сек...');
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                $('#btn_update').text('Повторно обновить');
            }
        });
    });
```

После нажатия на кнопку `#btn_update` в базе вроде как и происходит обновление (значение параметра `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` меняется), но значения для `json` не заносится, становиться пустым. Если вместо `text: allData` задавать какое-то статическое значение, то всё ок. Как в WP сделать так что б в базу писалось resolve от ajax функции. (файл ответа ~ 3.5Мб)

Comment: Зачем там асинхронный запрос? Смысла в нём ноль. Всё равно надо ждать ответа, прежде чем отправлять ajax. Уберите асинхронность.

Comment: асинхронность у запроса убрал. Но теперь выдает ошибку, что `response.json is not a function` не могу понять, что не так

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: А начать надо с того, что распечатать в консоли, что там в response

Comment: в responce приходит Promise {<pending>} [[PromiseState]] : "fulfilled" /// При вызове  let result = JSON.parse(response);  /// Приходит `Unexpected token 'o', "[object Promise]" is not valid JSON`

Comment: Если убираете async/await и по прежнему хочется использовать `fetch()` то используйте промисы `fetch('').then(response => response.json())then(() => {//...}).catch(() => {//..});`. По-сути async/await это тоже самое и попросту является синтаксическим сахаром. Сам по себе `fetch()` не поддерживает синхронные запросы, для этого можно использовать `XMLHttpRequest`, но нужен ли Вам здесь синхронный запрос, я не думаю, если честно.

Comment: Вам же просто нужен обычный аякс запрос, который по своей сути является асинхронным запросом.

Comment: А, ну конечно. fetch всегда возвращает Promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch Там самый первый пример с `.then` надо смотреть. И внутри then надо кидать ajax.

Comment: Вернул к вопрос задачи к начальному... рабочему состоянию. Вопрос - как выполнять запись в базу данных результат асинхронного запроса (3.5Мб), только после того как ответ вернется ? php пишет пустоту... не дожидаясь ответа `async function getData()`

Comment: @BlackStar1991 как и написали выше, Вам нужно отправить второй запрос внутри `getData().then()`.

Comment: Я этого не понимаю. Предположим, я отправляю `getData().then()`, как мне Вернуть значение ответа в базу данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле все проще чем Вы себе думаете. Вы уже делаете запрос `getData()` и внутри `getData().then()` Вам просто нужно сделать еще один запрос, теперь уже запрос с отправкой данных на бекенд, тот который у Вас `$.ajax()` ниже. Я его заменил на `fetch()`, так как немного странновато использовать и то и другое, потому оставил что-то одно.

```
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api1.test.com');

    return response.json();
}
getData().then((data) => {
    const text = JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t");
    fetch(ajaxurl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: `action=updateDB&text=${text}`
    })
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось, что надо было в базу отсылать значение `JSON.stringify(result, null, "\t");` а не просто объект или пропис. Ваш вариант написания намного компактнее.

Comment: нуждаюсь в уточнении - А как быть, если результат полученный таким запросом пишется в базу только частично ? (Исходный размер 41332, хотя должен быть 2.1Мб) Куда смотреть? В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: Нужно дебажить, так сходу тут не ответишь.